# when I am trying to scroll the react-big-calendar in mobile it is automatically pressing the events in day cell of month view

Tags: reactjs, react-big-calendar

```
import { Calendar, momentLocalizer } from "react-big-calendar";
import moment from "moment";
import events from "./events";
import "react-big-calendar/lib/css/react-big-calendar.css";

moment.locale("en-GB");
const localizer = momentLocalizer(moment);

export default function ReactBigCalendar() {
  const [eventsData, setEventsData] = useState([]);

  const handleSelect = ({ start, end }) => {
    alert("hello");
    console.log(start);
    console.log(end);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Calendar
        longPressThreshold={10}
        views={["month"]}
        selectable
        localizer={localizer}
        defaultDate={new Date()}
        defaultView="month"
        events={eventsData}
        style={{ height: "1000px" , overflowY: "scroll" }}
        onSelectEvent={handleSelect}
        onSelectSlot={handleSelect}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

when I am trying to scroll the react-big-calendar in mobile it is automatically pressing the events in day cell of month view. and I tried adding "longPressThreshold" with different values, but still I have the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to increase the `longPressThreshold` (default is 250ms).